# How to read lines from stdin (*in*) in clojure

Tags: clojure, stdin

I am writing my first clojure program, and want to read lines from stdin.

When I try this:

```
(doall (map #(println %) (line-seq *in*)))
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LineNumberingPushbackReader cannot be cast to java.io.BufferedReader (test.clj:0)
```

I get the same results in version 1.0 and 1.1

So how do I convert `*in*` into a seq I can iterate over?  I would have thought that this is common enough that `*in*` itself would be iterable, but that does not work either - if I try to use it directly I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.LineNumberingPushbackReader (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Also, are there any examples of doing general file handling in clojure?

Comment: replacing (map #(println %) (line-seq.. )) with just (map println (line-seq..)) could be nice

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try wrapping [`*in*`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/*in*) in a `java.io.BufferedReader`. And also use `doseq` instead of `doall`, as devstopfix pointed out:

```
(doseq [ln (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))]
   (println ln))
```

Note that [`line-seq`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/line-seq) is documented to require a [`BufferedReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) as its source.

Comment: This code does not work.  I get the error "doseq requires a vector for its binding"  Try was @devstopfix wrote.  It worked fro me.

Comment: @Jason Use dorun instead of doseq for this form. doseq requires a binding form. dorun forces a lazy seq.

Comment: How can use a escape for this loop?

Answer (score 25):

You should probably use [doseq](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doseq) instead of [doall](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doall):

```
(doseq [line (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))] 
    (println line))
```

[doall](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doall):

> Walks through the successive nexts of the seq, retains the head and returns it, thus causing the entire seq to reside in memory at one time.

[doseq](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doseq):

> Does not retain the head of the sequence. Returns nil.

Answer (score 25):

Just a note that for anyone who wants to only read a single line, there's the [read-line](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/read-line) function.

Answer (score 9):

For reasonably small inputs, the following would also work:

```
(let [input-string (slurp *in*)]
  (println input-string))
```

Or, splitting by lines:

```
(let [lines (clojure.string/split-lines (slurp *in*))]
  (println lines))
```

Comment: What is "reasonably small"? Why is this only appropriate for "reasonably small" inputs?

Comment: @EricIhli, [`slurp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp) reads *all* of the input that's available (until EOF, i.e. end of file).  So if there's a lot of input--at least many megabytes or several gigabytes, let's say--then you're loading all of into memory at the same time in a single variable `input-string`.  And then *after* that, you're printing all of it out at once. That will work if you have enough RAM in your system and if you've started Clojure with Java options that tell Java to use enough RAM, but you still might have to wait awhile before you start seeing the printed output.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the input line by line, allowing other parts of your code to pull lines from it as well. Having this in mind, I came to this improvement over previous answers.

```clj
(doseq [ln (take-while some? (repeatedly read-line))]
    (println ln)
)
```

And in case you want a complete input reading example, here is one:

```clj
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
(doseq [ln (take-while some? (repeatedly read-line))]
    (def parts (map read-string (str/split ln #" ")))
    (def ah (nth parts 0))
    (def am (nth parts 1))
    (def h (quot (* 12 ah) 360))
    (def m (quot (* 60 am) 360))
    (println (format "%02d:%02d" h m))
)
```

The above example reads lines from the input, each line containing a pair of integers representing the angle of clock pointer (0 to 360), then calculates and prints the time for each clock pictured. You can actually try the code in beecrowd online-judge [here](https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/3084), or may try [replit.com](https://replit.com) creating an input and running it with `clojure -M main.clj < input.txt`.