# How to read all lines from stdin in Clojure

Tags: clojure, stdin, clojure-java-interop

I'm writing a [Brainf***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpreter in Clojure. I want to pass a program in using stdin. However, I still need to read from stdin later for user input.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
$ cat sample_programs/hello_world.bf | lein trampoline run
```

My Clojure code is only reading the first line though, using `read-line`:

```
(defn -main
  "Read a BF program from stdin and evaluate it."
  []
  ;; FIXME: only reads the first line from stdin
  (eval-program (read-line)))
```

How can I read all the lines in the file I've piped in? `*in*` seems to be an instance of `java.io.Reader`, but that only provides `.read` (one char), `.readLine` (one line) and `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` (seems very low level).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read lines from stdin (\*in\*) in clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034059/how-to-read-lines-from-stdin-in-in-clojure)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could get a lazy seq of lines from `*in*` like this:

```
(take-while identity (repeatedly #(.readLine *in*)))
```

or this:

```
(line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))
```

which are functionally identical.

Comment: `line-seq` does exactly that, doesn't it?

Comment: Yep. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: The latter doesn't seem to work. `(line-seq *in*)` gives me `ClassCastException clojure.lang.LineNumberingPushbackReader cannot be cast to java.io.BufferedReader`. Have I missed something?

Comment: @WilfredHughes yes, you missed the fact that `*in*` needs to be wrapped in a `java.io.BufferedReader`, as shown in the example.

Answer (score 12):

It's simple enough to read all input data as a single string:

```
(defn -main []
  (let [in (slurp *in*)]
    (println in)))
```

This works fine if your file can fit in available memory; for reading large files lazily, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118123/read-a-very-large-text-file-into-a-list-in-clojure).