# Build a cli similar to `cat < operations.txt` in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I´m building a CLI on Clojure that will receive a file called operations.txt that will have in every line an operation that I want to process. Let's say:

```sh
clojure -M -m project.process < operations.txt
```

Right now I have a simple repo with deps and when I don't add the `<` operator I can receive the file name as an argument, but once I added the operator the arguments returns nil.

Is there something I can do for this?

I don't have to much added to my project other the what is created with https://github.com/seancorfield/clj-new command.

Here is the code on the main file:

```clj
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println args))
```

What I mean to receive in the arguments on this function is something similar that if I was using this:

```sh
cat < operations.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `<` on the command line, then the contents of 'operations.txt' will be available not as an argument to `-main`, but as stdin, which you can access via `*in*`.

You can use `read-line` to read a single line, or wrap it in a `BufferedReader` and process it with `doseq`.

```clj
(doseq [line (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))] 
    (println line))
```

See more details at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034059/how-to-read-lines-from-stdin-in-in-clojure).